# Move QWidget from one window to another (in PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, qwidget

The idea is, to pop a `QWidget` into its own `QMainWindow`. Beforehand it's the central widget of window A, and afterwards A should have a filler widget, a new window B is spawned with the widget as its own central widget.

So here's the setup:

```
class DetachedWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window: "MyMainWindow", widget: QtWidgets.QWidget = None, *args):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main_window = window
        window.set_widget(EmptyWidget(), False)  # sets new filler central widget
        if widget is not None:
            self.setCentralWidget(widget)
            widget.setParent(self)
        self.show()

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def detach_screen(self):
        self.windows.append(DetachedWindow(self, self.current_widget))
```

But when I try it, the `DetachedWindow` is just empty. When I replace `widget` in `setCentralWidget` with the constructor of a `QWidget`, it is displayed correctly. But not with the adopted widget.

What am I missing here?

**Update**: Apparently the widget is deleted. When accessing the `setText` function of one of its labels, the following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been deleted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but calling `widget.show()` afterwards solves the issue.

```
class DetachedWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window: "MyMainWindow", widget: QtWidgets.QWidget = None, *args):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main_window = window
        window.set_widget(EmptyWidget(), False)  # sets new filler central widget
        self.show()
        if widget is not None:
            self.setCentralWidget(widget)
            widget.setParent(self)
            widget.show()

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def detach_screen(self):
        self.windows.append(DetachedWindow(self, self.current_widget))
```

Any explanation for this? It does not really seem like this works as intended...